# Free draw form input box for human signatures

Tags: microsoft-word, forms

I have a MS Word document which is more or less a form with only the input boxes enabled for editing (the rest of the document is locked). I was wondering if there is some sort of solution or plugin out there that enables me to create a free draw box for users to scribble their signature in if they desire?

Comment: Would they sign via mouse or via a signature pad?

Comment: I guess just the mouse cursor would be initially fine.

Comment: I'm not sure about for the mouse, but companies like [Topaz](http://www.topazsystems.com/software/download/plugins.htm) have signature pads and they use ActiveX controls (really a no-no these days, but so be it) to capture a signature within the document itself.  You could probably get away with something slightly less robust in VBA.

Comment: Can't test this at the moment because my laptop is toast. But if you have Windows 7 and a reasonably up-to-date version of Office, you should be able to find some of the tablet functions that will do this. However, you do need some form of input device. Some of the latest laptops may be able to use their trackpads for this. Alternatively, this is a good job for a PDF file which has better security, there are certainly tools that let you add both a visible and electronic signature to PDF's.

Comment: Ok I guess I'll have to look into these options if there are no mouse draw alternatives. Thanks guys!